# Rails 3.1 build association not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, ruby-on-rails-3.1, model-associations

Ok so I have a method that should be returning a package (service_package_id and payment_plan_id) are passed in and valid. The packages model belongs to both service packages and payment plans and each of those models has many packages.

```
@service_package = ServicePackage.find(service_package_id)
@payment_plan = PaymentPlan.find(payment_plan_id)   

@package = @service_package.packages.build(:payment_plan_id => @payment_plan, :promo_code => "149", :price => "7.99", :number_of_free_days => "30", :setup_fee => "0", :initial_price => "0.00", :initial_price_duration => "30", :final_price => "0")
logger.error "package #{@package.service_package_id}"
@spackage = @package.service_package 
logger.error "spackage #{@spackage.description}"
```

Everything is great until the @spackage line. The logger picks up the service_package_id but then when next log occurs it returns with a nomethoderror on nil class. Why is my @spackage nil? This works on rails 3.0.9 but not 3.1 rc4 at least on my dev machine. Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you paste your association calls from your models please.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

The main gotcha here was that the model wasn't hitting the database (on purpose) but I had set up attr_accessor methods for payment_plan_id and service_package_id. Since I was passing the whole object in to the id attribute that attribute actually contained the whole attribute in memory. Once it starts hitting the database the build should work